# How to refer to a Kotlin delegating singleton object from Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, singleton

I have a Kotlin object that delegates it's implementation, in my case to `MutableSet<String>` like so:

```kotlin
object MySet : MutableSet<String> by TreeSet<String>() {

    init {...}

}
```

In Java I'd like to say something like `MySet.contains`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`object` declares a singleton. Unlike Kotlin, you cannot use a type name to refer to its instance in Java. Therefore, the Kotlin compiler translates the singleton instance to a field called `INSTANCE` instead, so you can do:

```
MySet.INSTANCE.contains(foo);
```

in Java.

While you can probably find `INSTANCE` by chance, just by using the auto-complete in IntelliJ, the only place where I could find this officially documented is in the [Calling Kotlin from Java](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html) page at the bottom of [this section](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-methods), which talks about calling static methods.

> ```
> object Obj {
>     @JvmStatic fun callStatic() {}
>     fun callNonStatic() {}
> }
> ```
>
> In Java:
>
> ```
> Obj.callStatic(); // works fine
> Obj.callNonStatic(); // error
> Obj.INSTANCE.callNonStatic(); // works, a call through the singleton instance
> Obj.INSTANCE.callStatic(); // works too
> ```